# "Who did pictures of upset?"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, questions

From 0 (word salad) to 5 (perfectly grammatical), how would you rank these sentences? I am particularly interested in whether (1b) sounds any worse than (2b) and whether (1c) sounds any better than (2c).

> (1a) who did friends of mine strike _ as a nuisance?
>
> (1b) who did friends of _ strike you as a nuisance?
>
> (1c) who did friends of _ strike _ as a nuisance?
>
> (2a) who did you think that friends of mine had struck _ as a nuisance?
>
> (2b) who did you think that friends of _ had struck you as a nuisance?
>
> (2c) who did you think that friends of _ had struck _ as a nuisance?

Comment: Is the underscore intended to be a placeholder for a name?

Answer (score 1):

**All of them are incorrect and ungrammatical.**

Maybe not "word salad" but with fundamental flaws.

Let's start from the beginning. The basic structure is:

> Asim struck Bart as a nuisance.

Asim is the subject, Bart is the object. Let's not worry about the exact parts of speech of "as a nuisance" since they don't change and don't affect the sentences.

Now let's make question forms.

> Who did Asim strike as a nuisance?

Answer: Bart. The question essentially asks who the object in the original sentence is.

Or

> Who struck Bart as a nuisance?

Answer: Asim. Now we are asking who is the subject in the sentence.

Now let's look At the sentences in the question.

1a looks like it is the first question form, asking who is the object, but it contains the answer: " friends of mine struck _ as a nuisance". Whoever is the _ is the object and this the answer to the question. It's the equivalent of writing

> Who did Asim strike Bart as a nuisance?

The answer is in the question so the question makes no sense.

1b and 1c are the same wrong grammatical structure, just switching nouns around.

All the three versions of 2 also have this same problem - adding " do you think " doesn't remove it. The sentence contains subject and object but asks what either subject or objects is.